# Enforce same-origin in Netlify function? (cors)

Tags: cors, netlify, eleventy, netlify-function

I am looking to enforce that requests come from the desired origin in `process.env.URL` in my Netlify site. But currently I can both `cURL` and make requests with Postman and get a response data back with a statusCode 200. Am I missing something?

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  try {
    let id = event.rawUrl.split("/").pop();
    let response;
    switch (event.httpMethod) {
      case "GET":
        response = await prisma.like.count({ where: { postId: parseInt(id) } });
        break;

      case "POST":
        response = await prisma.like.create({
          data: { postId: parseInt(id) },
        });
        break;

      case "DELETE":
        response = await prisma.like.delete({
          where: {
            id: parseInt(id),
          },
        });
        break;
    }

    callback(null, {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": process.env.URL,
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
          "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(response),
    });
    return;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return { statusCode: 500 };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS is a browser feature, ie, the browser obeys the settings. curl doesn't care about CORS and ignores it.

Comment: Thanks for the insight here, do you know do APIs typically try to protect against curl requests? 

I did run a fetch in a js console on a random website and was able to verify that CORS was working as expected.

Comment: I am NOT a security expert. If you want to check if the call came from the same domain, you can check the referrer header, but I don't believe that is 100% safe.